# What do JSONSerialization options do and how do they change jsonResult?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I am using `JSONSerialization` quite often in my project.
Here is an example of my `JSONSerialization` code:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]
```

**Note**: Options are missing for purpose and I normally have them in my project.

My problem is that I am not pretty sure what do these `options: []` do?

**What I have found about options:**

**NSJSONReadingMutableContainers:**

> Specifies that arrays and dictionaries are created as mutable objects.

**NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves:**

> Specifies that leaf strings in the JSON object graph are created as
>   instances of NSMutableString.

**NSJSONReadingAllowFragments:**

> Specifies that the parser should allow top-level objects that are not
>   an instance of NSArray or NSDictionary.

**Note2**: I found those definitions on : https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsjsonreadingoptions

**My question is**: 
Can someone please explain me differences between those options , what should I use them for and if you could show me some code example of those options it would be perfect :).

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Short answer for the first two options:

**Ignore them in Swift!**

In Swift you can make objects mutable just with the `var` keyword.

In Objective-C on the other hand you need

- `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` to make the nested collection types mutable `NSArray` → `NSMutableArray` and `NSDictionary` → `NSMutableDictionary`.
- `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` to make the value strings mutable → `NSMutableString`.

In both Objective-C and Swift if you are only ***reading*** the JSON you don't need mutability at all.

The third option `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` is important if the root object of the received JSON is **not** an array and **not** a dictionary.
If it **is** an array or dictionary you can omit that option, too.

The pair of empty brackets `[]` represents `No options` (the `options` parameter can be omitted in Swift 3+).

Comment: Thanks. Apple should write this in the first line of their documentation :-/

Comment: If JSON's root is not an object like `{ "myKey": "myValue" }` nor an array like `[ "myKey": "myValue" ]` would be, then can someone provide an example of such weird JSON in text format? Yes, it looks like `"myKey": "myValue"` (without anything enclosing it).

Comment: @Top-Master This is invalid JSON regardless of any option.

Comment: Hmm... I wanted to ask here, but thought I found it! So, then what does fragmented JSON looks like? any example is appretiated (except if `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` is useless).

Comment: Fragmented JSON is a single value type (String, Int, Double, Bool).

Answer (score 25):

You'd better know how JSON values are imported into iOS world:

```
 JSON array ->  NSArray
 JSON object -> NSDictionary
 JSON number -> NSNumber
 JSON string -> NSString
 JSON true   -> NSNumber
 JSON false  -> NSNumber
 JSON null   -> NSNull
```

(You'd better also check the RFCs of JSON. [RFC-4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), [RFC-7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159))

Then re-check the all options again:

**`mutableContainers` (`NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`)**:

Guarantees the `NSArray`s or `NSDictionary`s contained in the result must be `NSMutableArray`s or `NSMutableDictionary`s. Someone says in older iOSs `JSONSerialization` (`NSJSONSerialization`) returned mutable objects without specifying `mutableContainers`, but depending on it is not recommended, and actually you can find someones reporting such code does not work in iOS 10.

In Swift, mutability is represented by `var` and `let`, so you have no need to use this option in Swifty codes. Only needed when you cast some parts of the deserialized result to `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionary`. I strongly recommend to rewrite such codes in a more Swifty manner.

**`mutableLeaves` (`NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves`)**:

Guarantees the `NSString`s contained in the result must be `NSMutableString`s. Rarely used even in old Objective-C codes, ignore it.

**`allowFragments` (`NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`)**:

In old RFC (RFC-4627), only array and object were valid as the outermost component of JSON. If you expect array or object (`NSDictionary`) from the server, NOT specifying this option would help you to find the invalid returned value from the server a little bit sooner.

### Seeing the difference in codes:

Assume `data1` is a valid UTF-8 representation of the following JSON:

```
[{"name": "aaa", "value": 123}, {"name": "bbb", "value": 456}]
```

And the code:

```
do {
    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data1)
    let resultArray = result as! NSMutableArray //->This may cause your app crash
    //->Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x105e79c08) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x105e79cd0).
    print(resultArray)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
 
do {
    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data1, options: [.mutableContainers])
    let resultArray = result as! NSMutableArray //->This should always work
    print(resultArray) //->shows output...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And `data2`:

```
-1
```

And the comparison for it:

```
do {
    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data2)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error) //->Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
}

do {
    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data2, options: [.allowFragments])
    print(result) //-> -1
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`Options: []` is an empty array returns nothing.

Whereas `Options: []` can also be amend with:

- **NSJSONWritingOptions:** for writing JSON data like.

  - `NSJSONWritingOptions.NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted:` Specifies that the JSON data should be generated with whitespace designed to make the output more readable. If this option is not set, the most compact possible JSON representation is generated.
- **NSJSONReadingOptions:** used when creating Foundation objects from JSON data.

  - `NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers:` Specifies that arrays and dictionaries are created as mutable objects.
  - `.mutableLeaves:` Specifies that leaf strings in the JSON object graph are created as instances of NSMutableString.
  - `.allowFragments:` Specifies that the parser should allow top-level objects that are not an instance of NSArray or NSDictionary.