# how to get the JSONArray from jsonObject in Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

```
{
"status": true,
"status_code": 1,
"content": [
    {
        "cat_id": "3",
        "cat_name": "Food",
        "cat_parentid": "2"
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "4",
        "cat_name": "Entertainment",
        "cat_parentid": "2"
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "5",
        "cat_name": "Cars",
        "cat_parentid": "2"
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "12",
        "cat_name": "Personal Care",
        "cat_parentid": "2"
    }
],
"message": "Success"
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
do {
        //create json object from data
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
            completion((json as? AnyObject)!) //here completion callback will return the jsonObject to my UIViewController.
        }

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

this is my JSONObject. I am very new to the swift. how to get the content JSONArray and further process in swift.? Anybody can help me? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you serialized it?

Comment: in iOS you can covert your JSON into Dictionary using serialization and than parse your data

Comment: Yes. i serialized it . I updated my question . you can check now.

Comment: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: let number =  result?.object(forKey: "status") as! Bool
               
                if number == true
                    
                {                                                                                                       
                   let dataArr =  result?.object(forKey: "content") as! NSArray
                   }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code checks if the status is `true`, gets the array for key `content` and prints all values in the array.

The array is clearly `[[String:String]]` so cast the object to this specific type.

```
do {
    //create json object from data
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] {
        if let status = json["status"] as? Bool, status == true {
            if let content = json["content"] as? [[String:String]] {
                for category in content {
                    let id = category["cat_id"]
                    let name =  category["cat_name"]
                    let parentId =  category["cat_parentid"]
                    print(id , name, parentId)
                }
            }
        }
    }

} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

PS: As always, never use `.mutableContainers` in Swift. It's meaningless

Comment: can you explain me why not use .mutableContainers ? Please share any link for that

Comment: In Swift collection types are mutable by default with the `var` keyword. And assigning `.mutableContainers` to a constant (`let`) is useless anyway. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057854/what-do-jsonserialization-options-do-and-how-do-they-change-jsonresult/40058055#40058055

Answer (score 3):

Check whether your json has content array

```
if let content = json["content"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
      print(content) // it will give you content array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get content array like this:

```
let allContent = json["content"] as? [[String: Any]]
```

Full sample:

```
do {
        //create json object from data
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
            if let allContent = json["content"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for content in allContent {
                    let catId = content["cat_id"] as? String
                    let catName = content["cat_name"] as? String
                    let catParentId = content["cat_parentid"] as? String
                    print(">> catid=" + catId!)
                    print(">> catName=" + catName!)
                    print(">> catparentID=" + catParentId!)
                }
            }
        }

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extract you data by providing key

```
if let array = result["content"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
      print(arry)  
    }
```

Comment: it checks only for nil.it will print as optional not an array

Comment: `array` is definitely more specific than `Array<AnyObject>`

Comment: yeah , you can provide some specific type  ,   , great+1 @vadian

Answer (score 0):

```
let content = dict.objectForKey("content")! as NSArray
```

Then you can get json of single object for parsing by

```
for var cat in content
{
    print(cat) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way, by using the library.

First, import JSON library for Swift - [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and use the code:

```
import SwiftyJSON

let json = JSON(<jsonObject data>)

let contentArray: Array<JSON> = json["content"].arrayValue
```

**Library Integration**

If you're using cocoapods then use this pod:

`pod 'SwiftyJSON'`

OR else just drag `SwiftyJSON.swift` to the project tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can access like below

```
    if  let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "json"), let data = FileManager().contents(atPath: filePath) {
      do {
             let dicRes =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
             let contentArray = dicRes?["content"]
              print("contentArray == \(contentArray)")
         } catch {

         }
    }
```