# How to parse JSON when there is no key but only an Integer / String value?

Tags: ios, json, swift3

How can I parse [this](http://uhunt.felix-halim.net/api/uname2uid/felix_halim) JSON file ? My code is working  when both keys and values are available .

My code so far :

```
let url = URL(string: "http://uhunt.felix-halim.net/api/uname2uid/felix_halim")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
    print("Task Started")

    if error != nil {
        print("In Error!")
    } else {
        if let content = data {
            do {
                let myJSON =
                    try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: .mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                print(myJSON)
            } catch {
                print("In Catch!")
            }
        }
    }
})
task.resume()
print("Finished")
```

Comment: You can just cast myJson to int.

Comment: how ? @luckyShubhra

Comment: Its already answered by Vadian with explanantions. if let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? Int

Comment: O , yea ! I thought u have another answer , thank you @luckyShubhra

Comment: When I added comment ans was not visible yet. It was visible after refreshing tab. thatsy didnt include ans.

Comment: you can answer anytime , every useful answer is welcomed here ! @luckyShubhra

Comment: Thank you Rooy. Glad you could resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the root object of the JSON is not a dictionary or array you have to pass `.allowFragments` as option (btw. never pass `.mutableContainers`, it's meaningless in Swift)

```
let url = URL(string: "http://uhunt.felix-halim.net/api/uname2uid/felix_halim")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    print("Task Started")

    guard error == nil else {
        print("In Error!", error!)
        return
    }

    do {
        if let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? Int {
            print(myJSON)
        }
    } catch {
        print("In Catch!", error)
    }

}
task.resume()
print("Finished")
```

Comment: thanks @vadian , it perfectly works , would u plz describe various  `options : .` for `jsonObject()` ?

Comment: @Roy Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057854/what-do-jsonserialization-options-do-and-how-do-they-change-jsonresult/40058055#40058055

Answer (score 3):

**THIS ANSWER IS NOT CORRECT. IT IS POSSIBLE TO PARSE Int , etc like in vadian post**

This is not a json object format specification. 
JSON data must start with "{" for object
or "[" for array of elements.

http://www.json.org/

So, if you have got different formats I would suggest this:

Check the first letter. if "{" parse as object.

Check the first letter. if "[" parse as array.

Otherwise:

Just convert the String into Int something like this:

`var num = Int("339")`

If not use simple String.

Comment: But when i was trying to save the file , the default format suggested was JSON , btw . . is there any way to get data from here ? @Vyacheslav

Comment: @Roy , chech the first symbol. If either { or [ then parse it by JSON parser. otherwise try to parse like int (double) . If not use simple String.

Comment: That's wrong. JSON data may contain only a string or integer.

Comment: @vadian , ok. I will change the answer to improve

Comment: yes , I've read something like  this at http://www.json.org/ , do you have any answer ? @vadian

Comment: @vadian i've read. i mean that namely the object must start with "{"

Comment: @Vyacheslav Please see my answer. The linked article in your answer is quite old. You can find the actual specification here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159