# Cant get string response in swift

Tags: json, swift

I was able to get proper response using postman like the following
[image]

This is how i try to parse my response

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? String {
                print(json)
                // handle json...
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.progressHUD.hide()
                })
            }
```

The data is getting stored in my database properly, but iam not able to parse the response properly

It is showing this error

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Comment: `data` isn't JSON. Convert `data` to a `String` and see what you are actually getting. `if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { print(str) }`.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, let me check

Comment: ensure once its valid JSON or not

Comment: BTW - please confirm that the error you show is coming from the call to `JSONSerialization.jsonObject`.

Comment: If the response is supposed to be a single string you have to pass `.allowFragments` rather than `.mutableContainers`.

Comment: @vadian mutableLeaves ? -- > `.mutableLeaves`: Specifies that leaf strings in the JSON object graph are created as instances of NSMutableString.  --> FROM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057854/what-do-jsonserialization-options-do-and-how-do-they-change-jsonresult

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya No, `mutableLeaves`  and `mutableContainers` are for collection types and pointless in Swift anyway because you get mutability for free with the `var` keyword.

Comment: @rmaddy json is valid, this helped `if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { print(str) }` thanks working now!

Comment: What do you mean it's working now? That was meant as a debugging tool so you can see whether you are getting JSON or not. If that code gives you the string you actually wanted then you are not dealing with JSON at all.

Comment: @rmaddy That what I tried to explain you, He is getting STRING from API and he need to parse STRING not JSON

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya That's what I'm trying to confirm. Everything pointed to a problem parsing JSON but now it seems there is no JSON. If that's the case then you may have been correct. If so, sorry about that. Confusing question causing confusion. :)

Comment: @rmaddy Not an issue sir !! , You just missed image he posted where **BOOK0313** is written  which is string  :)

Comment: `if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                        self.progressHUD.hide()
                    })
                    print(str)
                }` i was able to get the response by changing like this, as mentioned in question iam trying to parse `string`, sorry if the question was confusing @rmaddy

Comment: thanks @PrashantTukadiya , it helped

Comment: @NavneetKrishna Yeah, you never had any JSON so you don't need to write any JSON parsing code. That was the confusion. No problem.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya sorry, you deleted the answer even before i could check, thats why i could'nt accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like this

Make sure data is not nil before

```
String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

Here is example

```
if if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
        self.progressHUD.hide()
     })
 }
```