# option[] in JSONSerialization

Tags: ios, swift

What is **option: []** in JSONSerialization in swift

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: updatedJson, options: [])
```

Comment: An *empty* set of options, i.e. no option is specified.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40058055/5362750

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`JSONSerialization.WritingOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/writingoptions) is an [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) and conforms to the [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral) protocol, which means that a “set of options” can be specified as an array literal. For example:

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json,
                                         options: [.prettyPrinted, .sortedKeys])
```

In particular, an empty array literal means “no option”:

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
```

In this particular case it would be equivalent to *omitting* the parameter

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
```

because it has an default value of `[]`:

```
class func data(withJSONObject obj: Any, 
    options opt: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = []) throws -> Data
```